# Verificação de espaços vazios de um formulário em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo meus estudos tentando finalizar um formulário na parte de validação (se não tem espaços em branco) em javascript e em seguida ele chamar o arquivo da função em php de envio dos dados por email, contudo, estou com problemas na validação pois sou um pouco leigo em javascript. Se alguém puder me dar uma dica "estou tentando aprender, não gostaria de uma resposta completa" eu gradeço. Fiz a validação junto no html após inserir o código do formulário.

---

Segue o código

```
<div class="box">
                    <form action="funcao.php" method="post" id="formulario_contato" onsubmit="validaForm(); return false;" class="form">
                        <div class="field half first"><input type="text" id="nome"  name="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
                        <div class="field half"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"  rows="6"></textarea></div>
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li>
                              <input  type="submit" value="Enviar Mensagem" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form> 
                </div>
```

Validação dos campos em javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validaForm()
    {
        erro = false;
        if($('#nome').val() == '')
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo Nome');erro = true;
        }
        if($('#email').val() == '' && !erro)
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo E-mail');erro = true;
        }
        if($('#mensagem').val() == '' && !erro)
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo Mensagem');erro = true;
        }   
    }
        //se nao tiver erros
        if(!erro)
        {
            $('#formulario_contato').submit();

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: precisa usar a biblioteca jquery

Answer (score -1):

Precisa usar a biblioteca nesse codigo

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Veja se funciona**

```js
   function validaForm()
    {
        erro = false;
        if($('#nome').val() == '')
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo Nome');erro = true;
        }
        if($('#email').val() == '' && !erro)
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo E-mail');erro = true;
        }
        if($('#mensagem').val() == '' && !erro)
        {
            alert('Você precisa preencher o campo Mensagem');erro = true;
        }   

        //se nao tiver erros
        if(!erro)
        {
            $('#formulario_contato').submit();

        }
        
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
                    <form action="funcao.php" method="post" id="formulario_contato" onsubmit="validaForm(); return false;" class="form">
                        <div class="field half first"><input type="text" id="nome"  name="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
                        <div class="field half"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                        <div class="field"><textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"  rows="6"></textarea></div>
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li>
                              <input  type="submit" value="Enviar Mensagem" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form> 
                </div>
```

Comment: Adicionei esta bibliote no head e depois acima da div como mencionou porém ambas não houve sucesso. Eu estou pensando que talvez seja alguma coisa entre input type sumit ou o action que coloquei. estou nadando nesse código faz 2 dias

Comment: Eu descobri! eu estava colocando o javascript no lugar errado no código (ainda pegando o jeito). Muito obrigado pela ajuda.